# Bootstrap 3 Splitting col-md-9 into two equal columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with the latest release of Bootstrap and I have the following:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h3>One Sidebar Section</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="col-md-6"><h3>Half Section</h3></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><h3>Half Section</h3></div>
</div>
```

But the above isn't working! How can I split my `.col-md-9` into two equal parts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your almost there, you just need to add a row surrounding the two col-md-6:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<h3>One Sidebar Section</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6"><h3>Half Section</h3></div>
   <div class="col-md-6"><h3>Half Section</h3></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See the documentation about Nesting Columns:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
<div class="col-md-9">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-6"><h3>Half Section</h3></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><h3>Half Section</h3></div>
</div>
</div>
```